# What is an output symbol?

Tags: stream-cipher, pseudo-random-generator, terminology

I'm reading Understanding Cryptography by Christof Paar and  Jan Pelzl. In chapter 2 (Stream Ciphers). There is a section talking about "Bulding Key Streams from PRNGs".

They assume a PRNG based on the linear congruential generator:

$$S_0 = seed $$
$$S_{i+1} \equiv AS_i + B\mod m, i=0,1,...$$

> where we choose m to be 100 bits long and $ S_i,A,B \in \{0,1,...,m-1\}. $ Note that this
> PRNG can have excellent statistical properties if we choose the parameters carefully.
> The modulus m is part of the encryption scheme and is publicly known. The secret
> key comprises the values (A,B) and possibly the seed S0, each with a length of 100.
> That gives us a key length of 200 bit, which is more than sufficient to protect against
> a brute-force attack. Since this is a stream cipher, Alice can encrypt:

> $$y_i \equiv x_i + s_i \mod 2 $$

> where $s_i$ are the bits of the binary representation of the PRNG **output symbols** $S_j$

> But Oscar can easily launch an attack. Assume he knows the first 300 bits of
> plaintext (this is only 300/8=37.5 byte), e.g., file header information, or he guesses
> part of the plaintext. Since he certainly knows the ciphertext, he can now compute
> the first 300 bits of key stream as:

> $$s_i \equiv y_i + x_i \mod m , i = 1,2,...,300$$

> These 300 bits immediately give the first three **output symbols** of the PRNG:$S_1 = (s_1,...,s_{100}), S_2 = (s_{101},...,s_{200})$ and $S_3 = (s_{201},...,s_{300}).$

(emphasis mine)

My questions are:

- What is an output symbol ?
- how we determine the output symbols (# of bits, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is an output symbol ?

An output symbol is the base "unit" of output of a PRNG. The keystream itself is composed of an integer number of symbols. If the PRNG outputs bits (like an LFSR), then the symbol is a single bit. If the PRNG outputs octets (like RC4), then the symbol is an integer in the range $[0,255]$.

> how we determine the output symbols (# of bits, etc)

If you have $n$ possible symbols, then a single symbol is described by $\log_2(n)$ bits. Generally, the number of output symbols for a PRNG are a power of two. This might not always be the case. If a PRNG outputted alphanumeric symbols with 26 different possibilities, then each symbol would hold $\log_2(26) \approx 4.7$ bits of information. It would probably be better to represent such a symbol as an integer in the range $[0,26]$ rather than representing it as a fractional number of bits.

The example PRNG in the question specified the symbol $S_i \in \{0,1,\dots m-1\}$ and additionally specified $m$ is 100 bits long. This means that each output symbol for that PRNG is a 100-bit value, although it could also be represented as a single integer in the range $[0,2^{100})$.